# RegExp adaption with new line

Tags: regex

I've the following RegExp to find the URIs listed above:

```
"^w{3}\.[\S\-\n|\S]+[^\s.!?,():]+$"
```

URLs to find:

1. www.example.org
2. www.example-example.org
3. www.example-example.org/product
4. You'll find it at www.example-
   example.org/product.
5. www.example.org
   You'll find it there.

Number 1, 2 and 3 will be found, but 4. delivers "www.example-" as URI.
When there is no point at the end of 4. it would deliver it correct.

**EDIT: With deleting `^` and `$` only number 5 is not working.**

Does anyone can help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern

```
^w{3}\.[\S\-\n|\S]+[^\s.!?,():]+$
```

can be simplified to

```
^w{3}\.[\S\n]+[^\s.!?,():]$
```

`[\S\-\n|\S]` this is a character class, no OR possible, no repetition needed, `-` is included in \S. So `[\S\n]` is doing the same.

`[^\s.!?,():]+` because you match every non whitespace with the expression before this one, here the + is not needed. I assume you just want your pattern not to end with one of the characters from the class.

See your pattern [on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufni) (I added `\r` to your first class, because the line breaks there needs it)

This is a very useful tool to test regexes

I think your problem is that you want to allow line breaks in the link. How do you want to handle this? How do you want to distinguish when the line ends with a link if the word in the next line is just a word or part of the link.  **I think this is not possible!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the '^\s' in the second squared bracketed part. Depending on your programming language, '\s' might match the new line. So, you are telling it to match anything that is not a whitespace and it finds a whitespace (new line).

However, this should only be one of your issues. Your regex uses the '^' and '$' characters which mean start and end of line respectively. Try this URL example:

> hello from www.example.org

Did it match? I think it will not.

Comment: Well thats right. Not using the '^' and '$' char will also match your example and my 4 examples. <br/>
But having another example (5. I edit my post at top) it returns me "www.example.org You'll"